# How to store extracted text from images in structured format in txt/doc file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ocr, google-vision

As I want to extract text from images(it a bank transaction statement), which I successfully did. But it's give me raw data. Not in structured Format as Shown in Image.

I have tried to do it by playing with their Vertices. But I just found to get 'description' and 'vertices' value in list format. How I move further to save it in doc/txt file in well structured format?

My Code:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:\\Users\\...."
client = ImageAnnotatorClient()
list1=[]
list2=[]
def detect_text(Image_path):
    with io.open(Image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    web_content = response.web_detection
    web_content.best_guess_labels

    texts = response.text_annotations

    for text in texts:
        #print (text)
        for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices:

            list1.append(vertex)

        b=[text.description for text in texts]

    list2=b[1:]
    print(list2)
    print(list1)
detect_text(Image_path)
```

I got output like this:

```
['IDBI', 'BANK', 'Customer', 'ID'......]
[x: 229
y: 241
, x: 2331
y: 241
, x: 2331
y: 3350
, x: 229
...
...
]
```

But Expected : to get output as bank statement look alike.i.e in Structured format. Which I can smoothly save and display in txt/doc file

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use textract library instead of any other stuff.

Reference link - https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Hope this helps.

Comment: found error.:                                                                                            
ShellError: The command `tesseract C:\Users\MUDRAC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8lxlnr38\conv-1.ppm stdout -l nor` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of your code with error?

Comment: This error giving me when path of image is there, on pdf it will work fine . but it's output is same like google vision api work. My problem is to save that extracted text data in structures format in txt/doc file.